# How do I query for an object with an object array property in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, database-abstraction

I have seen this asked before in different ways, but I'm hoping for a straight answer.

If I have two classes, Parent and Child, stored in two different MySQL tables, what is the best way of querying for a complete Parent object, with a list of all Children?

e.g.

```
class Parent {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   Children: Child[]
}

class Child {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

How do I get a list of matching Parents by name, with a list of children for each?

Do I have to write a query to grab all matching Parents, and then an additional query for each Parent to get all the Child elements?

This is obviously pseudo-SQL, but I'm hoping for something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
(SELECT * from c) as children from parent p LEFT JOIN child c on p.id = c.parent_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery in the select-list like you show in your pseudocode won't work because a subquery in that context must be a *scalar subquery*—in other words, it must return only one row and one column.

You can return a joined result set:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id, c.name
FROM parent p LEFT JOIN child c on p.id = c.parent_id;
```

But that will repeat the same p.id and p.name for each of the rows. Some developers find that hard to deal with (see my answer in [How to separate data in SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227146/how-to-separate-data-in-sql-table/47227383#comment81405557_47227383))

The alternative is to do two queries:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM parent p;

SELECT c.id, c.name FROM child c WHERE c.parent_id = ?;
```

Supply the p.id value as the parameter to the second query.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent table container child_id then

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,c.name,c.age from parent p LEFT JOIN child c on p.child_id = c.id
```

if your child table contain parent_id then

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,c.name,c.age from parent p LEFT JOIN child c on p.id = c.parent_id
```

in case a parent has multiple children then

```
select parent.name,(select group_concat(name,'|',age) from child where child.parent_id = parent.id) as child  from parent
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point... the parent can have multiple children.